# Database peformance optmization

Tags: mysql

We have a very big table which has around 250 million records. The table is growing bigger as every second many records are inserted. There is no update/delete operation done in this table. The table has structure similar to following sample structure

```
CREATE TABLE `sample_table` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `BatchNo` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LotNo` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ModelNumber` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Cost` decimal(4,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `QualityPercentage` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Type` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Vendor` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Send_Time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `InsertTime` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `VendorRating` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ProductType` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SerialNumber` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ItemID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BrandID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CategoryID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SubTitle` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'gl200',
  `Extras` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ModelNumber` (`ModelNumber`),
  KEY `SendTime` (`Send_Time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Problem**

The performance is slower, specially when we select to fetch records of bigger date range (Send_Time). Like if we try to fetch records from One years before to Now, it takes forever before mysql crashes.

We consulted with DBA and he said, as indexes keeps on changing every time as each minute many many records are inserted, the fetching will be slow, so he suggested -

1. Don't read and write from/to same database table "sample_table".
2. Create another database table, say "sample_fetch_table" with same structure as "sample_table"
3. "sample_table" will only be used to insert records from now onwards.
4. At night when write frequency is very low, fetch last 24 hours record from "sample_table" and insert them into "sample_fetch_table". Then delete inserted records from "sample_table".
5. Now use "sample_fetch_table" table to select and display records to webpage.
6. Archive X years old records to another archive table.

**UPDATE**

The common query we run is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sample_table 
WHERE (    ModelNumber = "12890" 
       AND Send_Time > FROM_UNIXTIME(1556515028) AND Send_Time < FROM_UNIXTIME(1556661540)) 
       AND (   (    Vendor in('11','12') 
                AND ItemID = 31 
                AND SubTitle LIKE 'ABC-123'
               ) 
            OR (    Vendor in('ABTU','RAST','RAMT','ABRT','ABNM')  
                AND UPPER(SubTitle) IN('RA200','PR55','XY100','TW20','D1EV','FR091','FR093','FRA12','AB23')
               )
           ) 
       AND BatchNo != 0 
       AND LotNo != 0 
 ORDER BY Send_time
```

**Explain of above query**

```
id = 1
select_type =  SIMPLE
table = sample_table
type = range
possible_keys = ModelNumber, SendTime
key = SendTime
key_len = 6
ref = (Null)
rows =  202042
Extra = Using index condition; Using where
```

We are bit skeptical about this suggestion. Is this optimal solution?? Is there any other better alternatives??

Comment: Can you add examples of the most common queries you run against this table? And the EXPLAIN plan of the specific query that takes long time?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ, I have update the Original Post

Comment: Optimization possibilities: 1) Divide `OR` on two separate queries combined with `UNION` 2) Normalize `SubTitle` by converting the data to uppercase for to avoid the function in the condition 3) Replace `LIKE` without pattern to equal sign `=` 4) Create proper **composite** index (something like `ModelNumber, Vendor, SubTitle, [ItemID,] Send_Time`, must be checked for each separate query type) 5) Find the possibility to decrease the amount of output records and, maybe, to avoid `field IN (list)`.

Comment: @WatsMyName how can you have a key on ModelNumber when you do NOT have a column named ModelNumber?  Try using real information for your questions, rather than edited that is error prone.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, There is ModelNumber Column, typo error, i have fixed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partitioning would be a Good Thing, given the size of table and its rate of growth.

That said, there are a couple of things you could try to improve the query before doing that.

> AND SubTitle LIKE 'ABC-123'

You're not doing any wild-card searching, so the "like" operator is unnecessary; a simple "=" would do.  But your DBMS might well be able to work that out for itself.

> AND UPPER(SubTitle) IN('RA200', ...

Now there's a problem.
Unless you have function-based indexes then the database has to scan every record, pass the SubTitle field through the Upper() function and then test the result of that calculation against the values in the "in" clause.  Scanning every record is what we call **Table Scanning** and, on a table this size, it's going to be slow!

You need to *fix* the data in that field so that it's *consistently* in upper case and remove the Upper() function call from the query.

> ... as indexes keeps on changing every time as each minute many many records are inserted, the fetching will be slow ...

If you're only adding new records, the index will be *extended* frequently, but index records that have already been written will be largely unchanged so, unless you're always looking for the most *recent* records, this shouldn't have *that* big an impact.

I'd expect the Table Scanning problem to hit you far harder than that.

> The performance is slower, especially when we select to fetch records of bigger date range (Send_Time). Like if we try to fetch records from One years before to Now, it takes forever before mysql crashes.

And what are you going to do with a whole year's worth of data having retrieved it? 
if you're going to do any kind of *aggregation*, look at pushing that back onto the database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in regard to partition, in which column will it be good to partition?? I tried doing it on `Send_Time` but got error `A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function`. Please note that Send_Time cannot be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the query and the table size, this looks like a good candidate for [partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning.html) on the `Send_Time` column.

Comment: Partitioning on Send_Time column in my test database, partition didn't work got `A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function
` error. Send_Time cannot be added as Primary key as Send_Time cannot be unique.

Comment: @WatsMyName The problem is caused by the fact that you have a key defined for `ModelNumber` that does not contain `Send_Time`. To solve this, you have to add the `Send_Time` column to the `ModelNumber` key.  You can check [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html) for more info.

Comment: So you meant Remove Send_Time as a key and add it with ModelNumber??

Answer (score 1):

```
INDEX(ModelNumber, Send_Time)
```

should be optimal for that query as it stands.  When adding that, DROP the index on just `ModelNumber` because it will be redundant.

`UPPER(SubTitle)` makes the expression not "sargeable", hence not a candidate for using an INDEX.  Instead, use a collation to obviate the need for `UPPER`.

However, the `OR` also prevents trying to use any of the columns in the `OR` part in an index.

Once you use the above 'composite' index, there will be no further benefits to be had from `PARTITION BY TO_DAYS(Send_Time)`.  If you plan to purge "old" data, then partitioning has a benefit.

Other notes:

Do you understand that `cost DECIMAL(4,2)` is limited to only "99.99"?

Some of the `INTs` could probably be shrunk.  (`INT` is 4 bytes; `SMALLINT` is 2 bytes but more limited in range; etc.)  Space has *some* impact on performance.

The list of instructions that DBA gave you are complex and provide little or no benefit.  The new table with one day's worth of data is no better than includeing a narrow range on Send_Time against the existing table.

If you have fetching data over a wide time range, does that mean a lot of rows will be returned?  If so, what will the client do with such a massive amount of data?